# git using local protocol

Tags: git, windows-server

If I want to use Git on an already existing file server just using file shares and bypass the need for ssh, would I just need to set up the network share as a remote on all the computers that will be pushing and pulling?

From the browsing around I have done, it seems like this is correct. Some of my confusion is coming from seeing examples of this all primarily in unix systems. I'm thinking that maybe the msysgit bash window helps to translate everything for you though possibly? If that is true, then I could add a remote by just executing: `git remote add myrepo //server/share` ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: mostly yes, see http://www.mingw.org/wiki/Posix_path_conversion